# Xcode 5.1: Where have the delta iOS 6/7 settings gone?

Tags: ios, constraints, xcode5.1

**Problem:**

Using Xcode 5.0 users had an option to specify some values, that would indicate, how a view ought to reposition itself when viewed on an iOS 6 (3.5 in) device rather than an iOS 7 (4 in) device.

As of Xcode Version 5.1 (5B130a), I can no longer find this functionality in the environment.

Can anyone provide information on where the settings have migrated?

**OR**

If the settings are no longer available is there a new official standard for how we ought to manage the difference in device heights?

I've already considered using constraints as a solution but I wanted to ask the community, if there are any official announcements from Apple?

I've parsed the Apple documentation but I have not seen this information presented.

**Xcode 5**

[image: Xcode5]

**Xcode 5.1**

[image: Xcode5.1]

Comment: the delta iOS 6/7 settings gone? No. Just uncheck auto layout :)

Comment: @TonyMkenu - Thanks, please post and I will accept answer. smh - I am sure I won't be the last one to miss the obvious.

Comment: Nothing has changed here. Xcode 5.1 is just like Xcode 5.0 in this regard. The deltas are about non-autolayout. If you have autolayout, you lay things out with autolayout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delta iOS 6/7 settings are still there, you just need to uncheck "auto layout";

Comment: Yes, I think ..  is time to start using the new auto-layout "feature" :) Happy coding and all the best!

Answer (score -1):

Back in February, Apple put out an announcement that they will no longer accept apps built for pre-iOS 7.  Shouldn't be too much of a problem however, since the vast majority of users use iOS7.

Comment: You can still support iOS 5 and 6. Your Base SDK must be iOS 7 though.

Comment: and depending on the app and users there is reason to support older iOS versions. Vast majority must not equal the most customers or users.

Comment: How is this an answer to the question that was asked?

Comment: -1: This answer makes it sound like you *can't* support iOS 5, 6, etc... this isn't true. As @rmaddy responds, this is about the `base SDK`, not the minimum iOS target version. Basically, Apple doesn't want you using Xcode 4.x or previous base SKD versions to build apps -- they want you to support iOS 7's new look.